# Spring security override specific message : Your login attempt was not successful, try again. - not found under org.springframework.security

Tags: spring, security

I would like to override this message to empty("") since Spring already spits out second message which I successfully overridden. Unfortunately I can't find location for this mysterious message..in the security library. Could you please help identify the location or at least its identifier so I could put it inside my messageBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is easy resolvable by custom login form. Since it won't display any of sf error messages we can pass error param back after processing. Consequently simply check for this param and add whatever text message you like.

`authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"`

then in our new login page simply add something like:

```
<c:if test="${error}">
<s:message code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials"/></c:if>
```

where you can use any message code from your resource bundle.